# How does one call a method with Tuples?

Tags: c#, methods, ienumerable

I have a method that looks like the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<double, double>> LargestTriangleThreeBuckets(List<Tuple<double, double>> data, int threshold)
```

How does one call such a method?  I currently have an array of doubles.  I have no experience with Tuples.  Thanks

Update: Many thanks to everyone. A little clarification: I am performing 16k fft's on a quadrature signal sampled at 192kHz. The resulting 16384 values need to be downsampled for the display which is typically less than 1920 pixels wide. To do this I have successfully implemented the LargestTriangleThreeBucket downsampling routine.  This routine is available on GitHub

I start with an array of doubles, outputBuffer[16384], put this in a Tuple list with x values going from 1 to 16384, and then call the method.

```
        var myList = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();

        for (int x = 0; x < fftOrder; x++)
        {
            myList.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(outputBuffer[x], x+1));
        }

        var result = LargestTriangleThreeBuckets(myList, 2048);

        temporaryBuffer = result.Select(item => item.Item1).ToArray();

        //output resulting buffer to the scope which is the user interface display of the signal

        scope1.Channels[0].Data.SetYData(temporaryBuffer, 0, fftOrder/8);
```

fftOrder is = 16384.  The code as is is executed in 1 millisecond, plenty fast enough for real time display. The result is a significant improvement over other methods of downsampling as far as I can determine.
Many thanks to all that helped here!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an array of tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490884/how-to-create-an-array-of-tuples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuples are just generic objects.  However you use the tuple, just imagine that you created a class with that many Items of the appropriate type.

For instance, Tuple< string, int, int> will give you myObj.Item1 as a string, and Items 2 and 3 as integer.  You can use it like this:

```
new Tuple<string, int, int>("Steve", 15, 22)
```

In the case of a list:

```
var myList = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();
myList.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(25, 23.333));
var result = LargestTriangleThreeBuckets(myList, 50);
```

Comment: Actually, that won't compile.  Call `Tuple.Create()` or specify the generic parameters.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for letting me know, coding from memory XD

Comment: Hi, Thanks.  So if I am starting from a one dimensional array, i.e. data[16384] I first need to convert this to a list with two values?  The array contains Y values for a line graph.  I guess I need to add in the X values?

Comment: Hi Tom. Because the largest triangle method takes a List, you're right, it'll need to be a list. And yes, you will need to add the x values to make them Tuples of X and Y

Comment: @Steve Thanks!  I'll give it a shot a little while later this afternoon.  I only hope the performance is good enough.  I am doing real time data collection sampling at 192kHz, feeding this to an fft and then to a graph. I have no problems performance wise averaging 16 full spectra at a time and then feeding it to the graph, this would be one added step.  Great, thanks for the help.  Hereis the link to the method I am using...https://gist.github.com/DanielWJudge/63300889f27c7f50eeb7

Comment: Hey Tom. Once its working you can focus on performance. You'll probably want to look at LINQ select for that, or some kind of streaming of the data. Of course, that's only if isn't fast enough straight away :)

Comment: Also, I have now reviewed the code you linked.  If you run into performance issues, there are many optimisations you can make to this method to make it faster.  We can discuss those if such a need arises.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
var result = LargestTriangleThreeBuckets(
    new List<Tuple<double, double>>
        {
            Tuple.Create(0.0, 0.0),
            Tuple.Create(2.0, 1.0),
            Tuple.Create(0.0, 2.0)
        },
    42);
```

I think, the method you are looking for is [`Tuple.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.create(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Just guessing but, [`PointF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointf(v=vs.110).aspx) or something from [`System.Numerics.Vectors`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors) might be a better representation of the corner of a triangle than a `Tuple<double, double>`.